# Unable to WRAP text in an Autocomplete Textbox column of DataGridView

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I created an Autocomplete Textbox column in DataGridView (Works Fine).

[See this image. This is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY7SX.jpg)

Now there is no problem until the text size is small but when the text gets longer it doesn't get wrapped in the column, the text gets trimmed.
[This is the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAqCc.jpg)

If I set the `WRAP` property of the column to `TRUE` then the textbox stops Autocompleting.
SO, its like either auto-completing or WRAPPING, but I need both...

I am putting my code below if anything can be done within it, have a look -

```
    Private Sub DataGridView2_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.EditingControlShowing


    DataGridView2.BeginEdit(True)
    Dim autoText As TextBox = TryCast(e.Control, TextBox)
    If autoText IsNot Nothing Then
        autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        autoText.AutoCompleteCustomSource = AutoCompleteLoad()
        autoText.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    End If
End Sub 
Public Function AutoCompleteLoad() As AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Dim str As AutoCompleteStringCollection = New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
    Dim ConnectionString As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("data source=ADMIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS; database=billdev;Trusted_Connection=yes;")
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT particulars from bill;"
    Dim SQLcommand As New SqlCommand(strSQL, ConnectionString)
    ConnectionString.Open()
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
    reader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader()

    While reader.Read()
        str.Add(reader.Item(0))
    End While

    Return str

End Function
```

Comment: Use a data adapter to fill a datatable.  Then use datagridview1.DataSource = dt.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: How is it going to make a difference?

Comment: When you automatically allow the DataSource to fill the DGV the auto scaling works so all the text fits into the cells.  I've found too many issues with manually setting a DGV where updating a scaling do not work.  Then only solution is to delete the DGV and add a new one.

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]
Maybe it has a bug in datagridview control.
we can do one cheat method to solve this issue.

1. in Datagridview_CellBegainEdit, set rowsDefaultcellstyle wrapmode = false
2. in DatagridView_CellEndEdit, set  rowsDefaultcellstyle wrapmode = true

Example:

*DGV.RowsDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False (CellBegainEdit)
DGV.RowsDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True (CellEndEdit)*

Its working for me.